# Set up nvidia drivers on iMac 21.5 (Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, mac

I am new to iMacs. I have set up dual boot on my new machine, Ubuntu 13.10 loads fine. Though, I clearly see that there are problems with graphics drivers. I have tried to follow some instructions found online, but this lead me to the reinstall of a system. Does anybody know how to properly set up graphics on modern Macs? In case this is important, the graphics card used is Geforce 750M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually very simple: just boot with `nolapic` instead of `acpi=off`.